# How do I make a GridLayout where elements fill the grid equally?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm trying to set up a layout that's divided into four equal quadrants.  With a bit of research, it looked like a `GridLayout` would be what I need, so I tried the following:

```
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/frame_border"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:layout_margin="30sp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/frame_border">
            <TextView
                android:text="A"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/frame_border">
            <TextView
                android:text="B"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/frame_border">
            <TextView
                android:text="C"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/frame_border">
            <TextView
                android:text="D"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </GridLayout>
```

`@drawable/frame_border` is defined as follows, drawing a simple white border around an element so I can see its exact bounds:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

  <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

  <stroke
      android:width="2dp"
      android:color="#FFFFFF" />

</shape>
```

When I define the layout like this, instead of four equal quadrants, I get a box like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
|A|B|                                           |
+-+-+                                           |
|C|D|                                           |
+-+-+                                           |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

If, instead of `android:layout_weight="1"` I use `android:layout_gravity="fill"` for the sub-layouts, I get the following, which is also wrong:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
|A|B                                            |
+-+---------------------------------------------+
|C|D                                            |
| |                                             |
| |                                             |
| |                                             |
| |                                             |
| |                                             |
| |                                             |
| |                                             |
| |                                             |
+-+---------------------------------------------+
```

What's the proper magic incantation to make it so that each of the four sub-layouts takes up half of the height and half of the width of the `GridLayout`, dividing it into four equal quadrants?

Comment: Before anyone asks, I'm using `LinearLayout` elements inside the grid because I want to put more complicated stuff in each cell.  I'm trying to get the basic proportions right first before I fill in the content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use like below, You can change** `TextView` to any `LinearLayout`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/choice_grid"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    app:columnCount="2"
    app:rowCount="2"
    app:rowOrderPreserved="false">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/frame_border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Tile1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/frame_border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Tile2"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/frame_border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Tile3"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/frame_border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Tile4"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: That looks good. I'm at work right now and can't review this, but I'll test it when I get home and accept this if it works. :)

Comment: This doesn't work at all for me.  You have several attributes in the `app:` namespace that need to be changed to `android:` namespace for it to even build, and then I get grid columns that are equal in width, but still only of minimal height instead of filling the grid.  I tried copy-pasting your entire XML as-is into my layout, but after fixing the namespaces, I get an exception: "Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout"

Comment: After removing the namespace, (simply using `<GridLayout>` as the tag name,) it loads, but the result doesn't look anything like the screenshot you posted, with all of the tiles squished to the top of the view and strange, inconsistent spacing and sizing.

Comment: @MasonWheeler hope before tring this you added this dependencies com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.3.0. Sync gradle and try again my code. it should definetly work.

Comment: Thanks, adding that package fixed it! :D